# Maximum range of projectile from elevation, simply?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

Let us say you have project a ball at velocity $u$ from a cliff hight $h$, and we want to find the maximum range of the ball. Ok so you could do this using equations of motion (for constant acceleration) find the range in terms of angle of projection and differentiate. This is easy, but a pain, the algebra is messy and can easily lead to mistakes. My question is, is there any way that we can obtain the maximum range using minimal algebra, differentiation etc. but rather uses e.g. geometry and physical intuition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the maximum height above the launch point with $$y_c = \frac{v_y^2}{2 g}$$ and draw a horizontal line at this height. Now you must know the initial direction of travel you can fit a parabola to this slope while being tangent to the height line at $$x_c=\frac{v_x v_y}{g}$$.

The general shape of the curve is $$y = y_c - K (x-x_c)^2 $$

By using the kinematic equations $x=v_x t$ and $y=v_y t-\frac{1}{2} g t^2$, as well as the parameter $\dot{y}=v_y - g t$ the parabola fit is

$$  v_y \frac{v_y-\dot{y}}{g} - \frac{1}{2} g \left( \frac{v_y-\dot{y}}{g} \right)^2  = 
\frac{v_y^2}{2 g} - K \left( v_x \frac{v_y-\dot{y}}{g}-\frac{v_x v_y}{g} \right)^2 $$

$$ \frac{v_y^2-\dot{y}^2}{2 g} = \frac{v_y^2}{2 g}-K \left( \frac{v_x \dot{y}}{g}\right)^2 $$

$$ K = \frac{g}{2 v_x^2} $$

So the geometric shape of the path is

$$ \boxed{ y = \frac{v_y^2}{2 g}- \frac{g}{2 v_x^2} \left(x-\frac{v_x v_y}{g}\right)^2 }$$

This is a simple as it gets. To find the range, you need to solve this parabola which is in the $y = Y- K (x-x_c)^2$ form. You do this with $$x =x_c + \sqrt{\frac{Y-y}{K}}$$ or $$\boxed{ x = \frac{v_x}{g} \left( v_y + \sqrt{v_y^2-2 g y} \right) }$$